# Using Meteor, useraccounts-core ensureSignedIn plugin won't except '/' route

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I am trying to use the ensureSignedIn plugin on all routes except for a front 'home' page that has buttons to login to separate parts of the site.

Here's my route for 'home':

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
```

Here's the line for the plugin and exceptions:

```
Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', {
  except: ['home', 'atSignIn', 'atSignUp', 'atForgotPassword']
});
```

Both snippets are from my lib/routes.js file, if that makes a difference. 
I've tried adding different route names in the except: portion, and they get correctly excepted, but I can't for the life of me get the 'home' route to not show "Must be logged in".

I've googled and read through gitHub issues and haven't seen anyone else with this problem, so it's probably something I'm doing wrong and not a bug with useraccounts or iron-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the name of the `/` route to `root`, then add that route name to the `ensureSignedIn` settings:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'root',
    template: 'home',
    action: function() {
        this.render();
    }
});

Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', {
  except: ['root', 'atSignIn', 'atSignUp', 'atForgotPassword', 'atResetPwd']
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm pretty sure I tried everything except the name: 'root' portion, which was what I needed. The code as you have it will throw an error though, just need to remove the function () from the first line to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: @soisystems You're right. Sorry about that. I go back and forth between node and Meteor all day, so I sometimes accidentally write callbacks when I don't need them in Meteor. I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: @soisystems there is a built-in route called "home" in AccountsTemplates, that's why it should throw an error and complain that "home" route is defined more than once.